# Variable change in multiple integrals: polar coordinates at zero.

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

We can make a variable change if we have some diffeomorphism $\phi$. A usual variable change is polar coordinates. But when $\rho = 0\quad |\phi'| = 0$, so $\phi$ is not a diffeomorphism if our region contains $0$. But anyway we do change and integrate. Why can we?

Comment: because the set $\{0\}$ have Lebesgue measure zero

Comment: @Masacroso We just use additivity of integral, one part is zero, in the other we make the change?

Comment: what you says is a way to see it

Comment: @Masacroso I just want to know  if it's correct. Thank you. (But what are other ways?)

Comment: yes, its correct. Any other way to see it is equivalent to the one you propose, it rely in the fact that integration on sets of zero measure are zero.